# 100% CPU usage when running WSL2 in Check Point Endpoint Security VPN installed environment

Tags: windows, vpn, cpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Every time I start WSL2, the CPU usage jumps up to 100%, the `System` process uses 20-30% CPU resource. But when I uninstall **Check Point Endpoint Security VPN**, the problem is gone.

[image]

I need both WSL2 and Check Point Endpoint Security VPN for my job, I can't just remove the VPN to resolve this issue. When I use Windows Performance Analyzer to analyze the CPU usage record, under the `System` process, there are many `n/a` sub-processes.

[image]

I have no idea what those are! Also, when I turn off my system, there is an unnamed program preventing shutting down. Please help, thank you!

*Edited*:

- Here is my WSL version info

[image]

- I try installing another WSL instance, but this time it's version 1. Surprisingly, WSL1 and Check Point Endpoint Security are working well which each other. The issue only happens with WSL2.

Comment: First, off, can you make sure it's really, really WSL2 (not WSL1)?  Sorry to ask what seems to be such an obvious question, but we have a *lot* of users that think they are running WSL2 (and, well, they are), but the *instance* (distro) ended up being a WSL1 instance.  `wsl -l -v` from PowerShell or CMD will tell you for sure.  I also ask this because I've seen far more CPU usage with security products when launching a WSL1 instance, since it actually runs more "like an app" than WSL2.  Also, the filesystem in WSL1 lives in an overlay that sits in the Windows drive, so it gets scanned.

Comment: Yes, I *really* use the version 2 of WSL, I have attached the picture of WSL version information in the question.

Comment: Ah, well, that would have been too easy, wouldn't it? ;-)  I don't have any experience with Check Point, so I can't give you a canonical answer here.  It appears to have both VPN and scanning features, either of which could cause issues with WSL. :-/  WSL1 usually plays better with VPN's, since it shares the networking stack with Windows (whereas WSL2 is a virtual NIC that is NAT'd behind the Windows network stack).  You might try creating a WSL1 instance just to see if it has the same issues  when starting up.  I'll keep thinking about this one in the meantime, though.

Comment: I've set up a different WSL instance using version 1, and there is no issue when I start the WSL1, the CPU usage is normal. But then I start the WSL2, the CPU usage immediately jumps up to 100%, the `System` process, again, uses about 20 - 30% CPU.

Comment: @TríPhan Have you tried playing with the `.wslconfig` settings? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-18945

Comment: Or https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-global-options-with-wslconfig